# OpenGL Texturing SPHERE using Soil?

Tags: c, xcode, opengl, texture-mapping, soil

Just wanted to ask a question on OpenGL texture mapping of a sphere. i want to create a planet(Earth) and i have tried to use SOIL for this because i found it to be the easiest but it's simply not working. All i am getting is a black screen. Could anyone check the code? Here it is:

Btw, its compiled using Xcode.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <SOIL.h>

GLuint texEarth;
GLUquadricObj *pSphere = NULL;

void OpenGLInit(void);
void draw_sun();
static void display(void );
static void ResizeWindow(int w, int h);

GLuint loadTex(const char* filename)
{
    GLuint tex_ID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(filename, SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,(SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT));
        glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_ID );
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        return tex_ID;
    }

void OpenGLInit(void)
{
    glShadeModel( GL_FLAT );
    glClearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glClearDepth( 1.0 );
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    pSphere = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(pSphere, GLU_FILL);
    gluQuadricNormals(pSphere, GLU_SMOOTH);
    gluQuadricTexture(pSphere, GLU_TRUE);
}

static void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texEarth);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_TEXTURE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef( -90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    gluSphere(pSphere, 1.0, 18, 18);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();

}

void initTex()
{
    texEarth = loadTex("earth.bmp");  
}

void draw_sun()
{


    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef( -90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glutSolidSphere(1.0, 15, 15);
    glPopMatrix();
}

static void ResizeWindow(int w, int h)
{
    float aspectRatio;
    h = (h == 0) ? 1 : h;
    w = (w == 0) ? 1 : w;
    glViewport( 0, 0, w, h );
    aspectRatio = (float)w/(float)h;
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective( 60.0, aspectRatio, 1.0, 30.0 );
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
}


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH );
    glutInitWindowPosition( 0, 0 );
    glutInitWindowSize( 1200, 900);
    glutCreateWindow( "Solar System" );
    OpenGLInit();
    initTex();
    glutReshapeFunc(ResizeWindow);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a call in your code that should generate an error:

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_TEXTURE);
```

`GL_TEXTURE` is not a valid value for `GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE`. From the [manual page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml):

> If pname is GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, then params is (or points to) the symbolic name of a texture function. Six texture functions may be specified: GL_ADD, GL_MODULATE, GL_DECAL, GL_BLEND, GL_REPLACE, or GL_COMBINE.

If you just want to use the value sampled from the texture, use this instead:

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
```

Then, your projection transforms the entire geometry out of the field of view:

```
gluPerspective(60.0, aspectRatio, 1.0, 30.0);
```

The standard perspective transformation looks from the origin down the negative z-axis. The near and far values specify the range of z-values. In this case, z values from -1.0 to -30.0 will be within the visible range. Since the rendered sphere is centered at the origin, it is not within the visible range.

To correct this, you can translate the sphere down the negative z-axis to get it within the visible range. Any value between about -2.0 and -29.0 should work, and will influence how large the sphere appears. As a starting point, add this `glTranslatef()` call to your `display()` function:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
glRotatef(-90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
gluSphere(pSphere, 1.0, 18, 18);
```